# What is the distance a creature or player can travel if they have multiple types of movement speeds?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

**What is the distance a creature or player can travel if they have multiple types of movement?**

For example, the [Ancient Red Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ancient-red-dragon) has a 40 ft walking speed, a 40 ft climbing speed, and an 80 ft flying speed. Can it move a total of 160 ft in a round using each of those fully, or is there another way this is calculated?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The answer to this is on page 196 of the PHB.

> ### Using Different Speeds
>
> If you have more than one speed, such as your walking
> speed and a flying speed, you can switch back and forth
> between your speeds during your move. Whenever you
> switch, subtract the distance you've already moved from
> the new speed. The result determines how much farther
> you can move. If the result is 0 or less, you can’t use the
> new speed during the current move.

So in the case of the Ancient Red Dragon, it can move up to 80ft each round, moving up to 40ft by walking or climbing or flying (or any mix of these), and moving the remainder by flying.