# What is the standard wording for a teleportation ability?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, homebrew, teleportation

I am attempting to create a homebrew ability to teleport as part of your movement, while still reducing your movement speed as if you walked and allowing you to split up your movement between normal movement or multiple teleports (eg. teleport 10 feet, attack, move 10 feet and then teleport 10 feet.) however wording it in an understandable way is hard, so far I have:

> As part of your movement, you may teleport a number of feet up to your walking speed to a point you can see, you deduct the distance you teleported this way from your speed

What is the standard wording for a teleportation ability in D&D 5e, and how do I apply it here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Make teleporting a mode of movement

There is no standard wording for expending movement to teleport. However, the [basic movement rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition) already allow for different modes of movement:

> Your movement can include jumping, climbing, and swimming. These different **modes of movement** can be combined with walking, or they can constitute your entire move. However you're moving, you deduct the distance of each part of your move from your speed until it is used up or until you are done moving.

If the ability makes teleporting a mode of movement, then the rest of the movement rules should work properly. **Such an ability could be worded like this:**

> You gain a teleporting speed equal to your walking speed. Teleporting is a mode of movement for you. You may instantly teleport to an unoccupied space you can see as part of your move, deducting the distance teleported from your speed as normal.

The creature could then use their teleporting speed in every situation that they would use their walking speed, including moving between attacks. If the creature also had a flying speed of 60 feet, they could teleport 30 feet, then switch to flying [as normal](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107367/47185).

#### Consider what side effects you do/don't want

Since teleporting is based on your walking speed, a creature that is grappled or restrained will be unable to teleport. If you want to avoid that, your teleportation ability will also need a specific rule to override it:

> Your teleportation speed is not affected by being grappled or restrained. It remains equal to what your walking speed would be if you weren't grappled or restrained.

Teleporting in this way would technically trigger opportunity attacks<sup>+</sup>. If you want to prevent that, you could add something like:

> When you leave a creature's reach using your teleporting speed, you do not provoke opportunity attacks.

---

<sup>+</sup> Credit to Revolver_Ocelot in the comments.

Comment: Instead of saying “deducting … from your speed as normal”, I would say “deducting … from your available movement as normal”; your speed is a statistic, it doesn’t change when you move, but your available movement is what changes when you use a mode of movement. Other than that, I think the wording is solid. Excellent solution.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I would have also done that, but the movement rules (confusingly) say, "you deduct the distance of each part of your move from your speed", so I mimicked that wording. I guess they mean to deduct the distance from your speed *and place the resulting value in a new variable called 'movement'*.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that reading.

Comment: As written, teleporting away does not prevent enemies from taking AoO. Depending on your goals it might or might not be desireable.